# Can't create an apt mirror using debmirror

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-14.04, gpg

I'm trying to create a mirror in my local machine, but I can't verify the gpg signatures.

Followed these steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror

The only difference I created the trustedkeys under /home/ubuntu/mirrorkeyring and repository files under /var/repository

Creating the keys:

```
mkdir /home/ubuntu/mirrorkeyring
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /home/ubuntu/mirrorkeyring/trustedkeys.gpg --import /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
```

From my mirrorbuild.sh:

```
export GNUPGHOME="/home/ubuntu/mirrorkeyring"
```

Executing mirrorbuild.sh:

```
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty/Release...      #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release ==> 200 OK
ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty/Release.gpg...      #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg ==> 200 OK
ok
Release gpg signature does not verify.
Ubuntu Release file: using Suite (trusty).
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-security/Release...     #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release ==> 200 OK (1s)
ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg...     #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg ==> 200 OK
ok
Release gpg signature does not verify.
Ubuntu Release file: using Suite (trusty-security).
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/Release...      #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release ==> 200 OK
ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg...      #** GET http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg ==> 200 OK
ok
Release gpg signature does not verify.
Ubuntu Release file: using Suite (trusty-updates).
Errors:
   Release gpg signature does not verify
   Release gpg signature does not verify
   Release gpg signature does not verify
   Failed to download some Release or Release.gpg files!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to use root reading the file from the standard .gnupg folder and worked.